# NullPointerException while attempting to create table

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to follow the example at

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/persistence-modules/spring-data-cassandra/src/test/java/org/baeldung/spring/data/cassandra/repository/BookRepositoryIntegrationTest.java

When I try to create a new table as

`adminTemplate.createTable(true, CqlIdentifier.of("book"), Book.class, new HashMap<String, Object>());`

I get a `NullPointerException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.whi.breastadvisor.contoller.test.MyIntegrationTestClass.setUp(MyIntegrationTestClass.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:178)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

what am i doing wrong?

here is what i have at the beginning of the class

```
@Autowired
private CassandraAdminOperations adminTemplate;

public static final String KEYSPACE_CREATION_QUERY = "CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS myKeyspace WITH replication = { 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3' };";

public static final String KEYSPACE_ACTIVATE_QUERY = "USE myKeyspace;";
```

Do I need anything else? Here is my setup function

```
        try {
            EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra();
        } catch (ConfigurationException e1) {
            logger.error(e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw e1;
        } catch (TTransportException e1) {
            logger.error(e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw e1;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            logger.error(e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw e1;
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            logger.error(e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
            throw e1;
        }

        final Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").withPort(9142).build();
        logger.info("Server Started at 127.0.0.1:9142... ");
        final Session session = cluster.connect();
        session.execute(KEYSPACE_CREATION_QUERY);
        session.execute(KEYSPACE_ACTIVATE_QUERY);
        logger.info("KeySpace myKeyspace created and activated.");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        try {

            logger.info("Will try to create book table");
            adminTemplate.createTable(true, CqlIdentifier.of("book"), Book.class, new HashMap<String, Object>());
            logger.info("book table created");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            logger.error("Could not create table", e);
            throw e;
        }
```

Comment: Probably your adminTemplate is not set. Check your dependency injection.

Comment: did you inject `@Autowired private CassandraAdminOperations adminTemplate;` correctly ?

Comment: yes, i have `@Autowired
 private CassandraAdminOperations adminTemplate;`

Comment: does `adminTemplate` need to be static?

Comment: For God's sake no :) Your dependency is not working.

Comment: what does it mean dependency is not working? do you mean something wrong in my pom?

Comment: He means maybe Spring could not `@Autowire`, causing `adminTemplate` to be `null`.

Comment: oh ok i see. yes, i checked and indeed the `adminTemplate` is `null`. why would this happen? am i missing something in my pom?

Comment: do i need to add something in my spring-beans.xml?